# Signed Mac Apps - error message

Tags: code-signing

Will the message " is damaged and can't be opened. You should move it to the Trash" occur even if you just rename the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming the application won't actually change anything in the file itself, hence not affect the restrictions from the App Signing, so no, it will not.